# Android App show white page When tap app icon on nexus 4

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-4

When tap app icon On Nexus 4 so Android App show white page!

But it run successfully On first launch after installation

I defined splash screen with resources :

drawable-mdpi : 425 x 701

drawable-hdpi : 638 x 1052

drawable-sw800dp: 638 x 1052

drawable-xhdpi: 850 x 1401

issue seen OS versions : 5.1 (lenovo Tablet) And 6.0.1 (Nexus 4)
IDE : IntelliJ Idea

Comment: do you have any logcat?

Comment: Do you have splash screen in your app ?

Comment: are you splash screen ?

Comment: Yes I Have splash screen

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi salam dada, I dont have access to device, customer told me about this issue

Comment: Make sure you disable InstaRun while giving you debug build to your client

Comment: Do you put your first activity layout in special layout size or api version? some thing like this : layout-v21 or layout-large

Comment: Please put your logcat

Comment: @ramineftekhari No, I didn't,  no problem on my devices, customer sent feedback to me!

Comment: dada! in your future projects, use firebase to get logcat from users ;)